# Using the variables of some screen in another one with Kivy

Tags: python, variables, kivy, screen

I am trying to create a 3 screens GUI with Kivy. One of the screens is calculating a value which contains several integers and list (result of a function). 
But my problem is that I don't get how to use this value in others screen. 
I assume that I'll have to use Screen Manager but how ?
This is a really basic understanding issue I guess so I just did the following example to illustrate :

```
class firstscreen(screen):
    def btn_pressed(self):
        self.a=1

class secondscreen(screen):
    def btn2_pressed(self):
        print(a)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm=WindowManager()
screens = [firstscreen(name="1"), secondscreen(name="2")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "import"

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

How can I use a in the second screen ?

edit : i tried to use :

```
self.manager.get_screen('firstscreen').a
```

But it tells me that fisrtscreen doesn't exist :o

Comment: Why would `firstscreen` exist, you named them `"1"` and `"2"` so refer to them that way.

Comment: It was not the real names in this example but I actually did the same mistake in my code, so issue solved ty :)